# $result = $db->query('SELECT max(galleryid) FROM img WHERE parentimgid='.$id.' ')

Tags: php, mysql

$db = Db::getConnection();

$result = $db->query('SELECT max(galleryid) FROM img WHERE parentimgid='.$id.' ')

i need this query $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); only gallery id please help

Answer (score 1):

Needless to say this is quite unsafe/obsolete way of fetching data in PHP, but anyways;

$row is an array, max(galleryid) is first (and the only) member of that array;

```
$gallery_id = $row[0];
```

and your corrected query will be:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT max(galleryid) FROM img WHERE parentimgid='.$id)
```

[PHP: mysql_fetch_row - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Comment: $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);  this function not working  in $result i need one max(galleryid)

Comment: expanded my answer

Answer (score 0):

$db = Db::getConnection();

```
    $sql = 'SELECT max(galleryid) AS max FROM img WHERE parentimgid = :id';


    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);


    $result->execute();


    $row = $result->fetch();
    return $row['max'];
```